# PHP errors. Trying to connect a form in PHP to my MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to connect my website to a database, by adding whatever someone writes from the form to a table in my database, but so far I've only gotten errors and nothing appears on my MySQL database.

The error that I keep getting are these two:

> Notice: Undefined index: fill
>
> Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in (folder)

How do I proceed to solve this problem?

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
        <label for="fill">Add:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fill">
    
    <input type="submit" value="Insert!">
</form>



<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die ("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

else
{
    echo 'Connected to database';
}

mysql_select_db($dbname);


$sql = "INSERT INTO card_refill ('refill') VALUES ('$_POST[fill]')";


mysql_close($conn)

?>
```

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. That won't work.

Comment: `$conn` is mysqli object. You are trying to close as mysql object

Comment: How do I change it so that It'll work? I tried changing the mysql functions over to mysqli functions and it didnt work.

Comment: You need to wrap the word 'fill' in your $_POST with single quotes.

Comment: @Filthy_Rich Ive already done that but i keep getting the error: 
Notice: Undefined index: fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the dbname is already provided in `mysqli_connect` function, `mysql_select_db($dbname)` is not necessary. As for the execution of the query, SQL string should be run via `mysqli_query` function. However before running SQL queries, the variables need to be sanitised to prevent SQL injections and XSS attacks.

Try something like this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die ("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
    echo 'Connected to database';
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO card_refill ('refill') VALUES ({$_POST['fill']})";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
//do whatever you need to do with the result

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: by the way you should never use post data directly in your queries.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Ok, I'll clarify.  Since the dbname is already provided in mysqli_connect function, mysql_select_db($dbname) is not necessary.  As for the execution of the query, sql string should be run via mysqli_query function. However before running sql queries, the variables need to be sanitized to prevent sql injections.

Comment: One more thing, you should use quotation marks around the key string to access array members. ex: $_POST['fill'] rather than $_POST[fill]

Comment: I'll edit my post but please try not to "dictate" next time.

Comment: I am not "dictating" anything, but if you'd like I can hoist a flag. ;-) If you thought I was dictating something you may want to check your skin.

Comment: @kunoichi I keep getting errors regarding the line $_POST['fill'] . Ive wrote it correctly and ive checked it multiple times but I keep getting the error Unidentified Index: fill. 

What gives?

Comment: @SubinThomas Yes. Both are in the same PHP file

Answer (score 1):

This database insert part should be done only if you press the submit of form. So use `isset` to detect submit.

Put all the php code inside a if loop.

```
if(isset($_POST['fill']))   //execute only if fill is set
{
$conn = mysqli_connect......;
// all your codes here
mysqli_close($conn);
}
```